# js - Fire event on midnight

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple web app using javaScript. At one part I want an event to fire when the date changes (i.e., 4th Jan becomes 5th Jan).

This is what I am doing:

```
window.onload=function(){
var today = new Date();
var tommorow = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+1);
var timeToMidnight = (tommorow-today)/60;
var timer = setTimeout(function(){console.log("this");},timeToMidnight);
}
```

Anyhow, the problem I am facing is that the function is getting executed around 30-40 seconds before it is actually midnight. What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: @dystroy Don't know, that's how it was from wherever I copied it.

Comment: When you convert dates to numbers, you get milliseconds. That's the unit required by setTimeout. You don't have to divide. But you shouldn't copy code without understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you convert dates to numbers, you get milliseconds (see [Date.prototype.valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)).

[That's the unit required by `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout). So you don't have to divide.

Change

```
var timeToMidnight = (tommorow-today)/60;
```

to

```
var timeToMidnight = (tommorow-today);
```